# i would like to have drawable button Horizontally with top position hint

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button

I would like to have drawable button Horizontally with top position hint.

[image: something like this]]

I tried to do it but I don't know how to display the hint text or the upper text.

```
    <Button
    android:id="@+id/test"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Chip.Filter"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="79dp"
    android:background="@color/float_transparent"
    android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_clear"
    android:textAppearance="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Chip.Filter"
    android:hint="@string/title_About"
    android:text="@string/title_About"
    android:textAlignment="textStart"
    android:textColor="@color/links"
    android:textColorHint="@color/gray_btn_bg_color"
    android:textSize="20dp"/>
```

[image: this what i did so far]

Answer (score 0):

First - don`t use fixed size on views - it makes your screen not responsive.

Second - you can use [constraintlayout](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout) to achieve this really fast:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:text="Jun 10 ,2018"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:text="TextView"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView4"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView4" />
```

Answer (score 0):

**try this one**

```
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">


<Button
    android:id="@+id/text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:hint="DUE DATE"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:textAlignment="viewStart"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/text2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:text="Jun 10 ,2018"
    android:textAlignment="viewStart"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/text1"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```